# "In" versus "con" in una frase particolare

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Quale tra queste due frasi è quella corretta?

- Vado sempre al lavoro *in* un treno locale.
- Vado sempre al lavoro *con* un treno locale.

Comment: Definitely the second!....scusa, la seconda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visto che vuoi indicare la modalità con la quale vai a lavoro devi usare il complemento di modo o maniera.

Si usano *in* o *col* (*con il*) quando il modo è un mezzo di trasporto generico

> Vado sempre a lavoro **in** treno.
>
> Vado sempre a lavoro **col** treno.

Si usa *con un* quando ci si riferisce ad un certo tipo di mezzo di trasporto (ad es. + aggettivo).

> Vado sempre a lavoro **con un** treno *locale*.
>
> Vado sempre a lavoro **con un** treno *affollatissimo*.

Si usa *col* quando ci si riferisce ad un esatto mezzo di trasporto

> Vado sempre a lavoro **col** treno delle 7:30, quello sempre affollato.

Quindi la prima frase non è corretta. Sforzandosi, uno può dedurne che una volta hai affermato di fare un lavoro che si svolge all'interno di un treno locale e che quella affermazione sia ancora vera, nel senso che non sei stata promossa ai treni nazionali. Ma per se uno avvesse voluto dire questo avrebbe detto piuttosto

> Lavoro sempre in un treno locale.

o

> Continuo a lavorare in un treno locale.

Answer (score 0):

In un treno locale -> lavori sul treno

Con un treno locale -> Vai al lavoro per mezzo del treno

Per dire il mezzo puoi anche usare *in treno*, ma senza aggettivi: quindi non *in treno locale*